# Как сделать Шардиринг в mysql?

Tags: mysql

Мне нужно сделать шардеринг между серверами в mySql, как сервер использую asp.core, не могу найти литературу на это или готовое решение может кто знает как это можно сделать?

Comment: [MySQL NDB Cluster: Scalability](https://www.mysql.com/products/cluster/scalability.html)

Comment: @tym32167, Я как понимаю, для этого ноды которые подключаются к главному серверу, должны иметь белый IP, а есть возможность чтобы этого не было, чтобы только у главного сервера был белый IP

Comment: *Мне нужно сделать шардеринг между серверами в mySql* 1) Шардинг (не "шардеринг") - какой? вертикальный? горизонтальный? 2) Шардинг - он не между серверами, он шардинг данных (как правило, таблицы). Вам точно нужен именно шардинг?

Comment: @Akina, Ну я как понял мне нужен шардинг. Сейчас попробую объяснить: 
У меня будет главный сервер, на котором будет все данные. И будут предприятия(ноды) с локальным БД. И нужно чтобы была синхронизация БД, таким образом, чтобы у предприятия были только его данные, а на главном все данные. Надеюсь понятно объяснил. Таблицы одинаковые, Только данные
Или все же это репликация с фильтром?

Comment: Это не шардинг. Это самая обычная репликация. Мульти-мастер.

Comment: @Akina, Но там же для мульти-мастер все сервера должны быть с белым IP или я не то читаю, то у меня часть серверов, будет без белового  IP и лушче всего настроить запросами http/https к главному

Comment: Да, никто не мешает "вручную" реализовывать то, что есть штатно. Если Вы настолько верите в себя - делайте.

Comment: @Akina, Я не верю в себя) Я как ищу готовое решение, которое мне подойдет